# Query for to avoid conflicts for different time slots

Tags: mysql, performance

I have looked for this in several places but not necessarily found the right answer.

I am trying to query for available providers in a given time range. I have one column which has all the old bookings with a date_start and date_end. Basically, if I want to make a booking, I need to make sure that my providers are available. So far the query works and goes like this:

```
  SELECT a.provider a
      FROM l_provider_zip a 
      (several inner Joins and conditions)
      WHERE a.zip = :zip 

 AND a.provider_id  
 NOT IN (
     SELECT da.provider_id
     FROM booking da
     WHERE da.provider_id IS NOT NULL
       AND (
              ( :start BETWEEN da.date_start AND da.date_end) 
           OR ( :end  BETWEEN da.date_start AND da.date_end) 
           OR ( da.date_start BETWEEN :start AND :end )
           )
)
```

My concern is that in order to find whether a provider that is available for the new booking, I need to make sure that the new booking does not conflict with a different booking. Here I have 3 conditions statements to figure it out.

1. :start(of the new booking) BETWEEN da.date_start AND da.date_end
2. :end(of the new booking) BETWEEN da.date_start AND da.date_end
3. da.date_start BETWEEN :start AND :end  (another booking is not in the start or end of the new one)

This seems quite inefficient but I'm cannot find a a better way. Of course I can make it more efficient by indexing but is there a better way of performing this operations. This is quite a central query to my project and I think it might be an issue many have faced and will keep on facing. Thanks again!

Comment: Don't the first and third conditions entail the second (i.e. the second is unnecessary)?  I can't see a situation where 2 would be true but 1 and 3 would not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood your question, you are looking for providers who are available for this booking, i.e. for those that don't have a booking that clashes with this booking). So to find all bookings that clash with this booking you need to look for bookings

```
- where the booking start date is on or before the new booking end date, and
- where the booking end date is on or after the new booking start date
```

So for your sub-query that would translate to

```
 SELECT da.provider_id
 FROM booking da
 WHERE da.provider_id IS NOT NULL
   AND da.date_start <= :end 
   AND da.date_end   >= :start
```

Comment: I like this, but I think I'd convert the "not exists" to a "not in" to reduce the amount of rows returned by the sub query:
NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM booking da WHERE da.provider_id = a.provider_id AND da.date_start <= :end AND da.date_end   >= :start)

Comment: @TheVedge I guess, depending on the other JOINs you might be able to LEFT JOIN on the query above and use an IS NULL which might improve performance. Hard to know without seeing the OP's full schema, EXPLAIN output etc

Answer (score 1):

I would join the providers to bookings in the specified date range, and then exclude those providers since they're taken:

```
/* Select all providers */
SELECT *
FROM l_provider_zip p
/* Providers with bookings that start in the middle of our date range are busy */
LEFT JOIN booking b1
  ON b1.provider_id = p.provider_id
  AND b1.date_start BETWEEN :start AND :end
/* Providers with bookings that end in the middle of our date range are busy */
LEFT JOIN booking b2
  ON b2.provider_id = p.provider_id
  AND b2.date_end BETWEEN :start AND :end
/* Exclude those providers with bookings in our date range */
WHERE b1.provider_id IS NULL
  AND b2.provider_id IS NULL
```

No subqueries needed! Let me know if you need help with the indexes to make this query perform well.